# Setting ItemsControl background to a SystemColor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) which i want to set its background to the color of an empty client according to the current system theme, i though i could do it like this:

```
<ItemsControl Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColor}}" />
```

but when i try this, the [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) isn't shown as its background is rendered Transperent and only settings it to a local brush would do the job.
How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Background` property is of `Brush` type. Moreover, you're using DynamicResource extension. So you have to define resource key, not resource itself in you declaration:

```
<ItemsControl Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, and it doesn't work either. and i think there is a converter that makes it possible to use SystemColors.WindowColor

Comment: It works now, i wonder why it didn't throw any kind of extension.